# Postgres, define a constant (or function) with a number value for check constraint comparisons

Tags: sql, postgresql, constants

I'm trying to create a "constant" or a "function that returns a constant" for check constraint comparisons such as the following:

```
create or replace function max_num() returns numeric language sql immutable parallel safe as
    133137223119940041836849736350226675204;

create table thing (
  amount numeric(39) not null check (amount <= max_num())
)
```

Apparently this isn't valid PSQL though, so I was hoping someone could tell me how I can achieve the same or similar in Postgres? The reason I would like it in a constant is because I need to do this check constraint on more than 1 column.

PSQL version: `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 12 there is no need for the function to have an argument:

```
select version();
                                                 version                     

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623
 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
(1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION max_num()
RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
    SELECT 13::numeric;
$func$
        ;
CREATE FUNCTION

CREATE TABLE THING (
  amount numeric(39) NOT NULL CHECK (amount < max_num())
);
CREATE TABLE

INSERT INTO thing(amount) VALUES ( 12);
INSERT 0 1

INSERT INTO thing(amount) VALUES ( 14);
ERROR:  new row for relation "thing" violates check constraint "thing_amount_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14).
```

Comment: This works with all supported Postgres versions: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5996d14355b78017f72c41d1610675aa

Comment: I get this error: 
`pq: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$func$. 
select 133137223119940041836849736350226675204::numeric" handling file.sql`

Comment: Please adapt the code I have posted including all `$func$`.

Comment: I don't understand sorry. My function looks almost identical to yours: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c717d529e942d63eacd006190b47778

Comment: @nbio: your function works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=531157a49ccf81cef357c40c87a628fe

Comment: Works there, doesn't work in my local postgres v12, very odd...

Comment: @nbio Post exactly the code you are running and its output with `psql -e -f yourscript.sql`.

Comment: @pifor I think this might actually be something related to my migration tool or postgres driver and not postgres itself (or your answer), so I'll mark this one as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help, I'll have to dig into this one a bit further it seems...